# java keytool self signed certificate use in firefox to trust changing DSL home IP-addresses

Tags: java, firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

My web applications runs at home and shall be accessed through NAT. Of course my DSL provider assigns varying IP-addresses to my home, so I get into the following situation:

The setup:

- The web application is implemented on Jetty.
- A certificate was created with Java keytool and installed in Jetty.
- I have my private way to "guess" the IP address at home (not a dyndns provider).
- I can successfully access the web application from anywhere.

So everything is fine, except:

Whenever the DSL provider has changed my IP-address, I need to go through the three steps of telling firefox that the certificate is ok, which tends get annoying.

I exported the certificate with

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore WEB-INF/conf/hk_ssl_keystore -storepass XXXX -alias Einkaufsliste -file Einkaufsliste.cert
```

and tried to import it into Firefox under Edit->Preferences->Advanced->View Certificates->Authorities but this results in

```
This is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can't be imported into the certificate authority  list.
```

Now I wonder if I can tell firefox (and likely other browsers) that I am its master and I tell it by decree that this very certificate is trusted by me so there is no need to worry again?

Answer (score 0):

Try in 'Your Certificates' tab. It should work there. Authorities tab is for 'trusted authorities' and providers. Self signed certificates are not imported there.

Comment: Will try this out anyway, but I doubt it will work. 'Your Certificates' contains certificates that identify me against servers, but I want a server identified.